# R - simulate model result

Tags: r, glm

I have an glm model in R, it calculates some score. I have source data, coeficients, model, but I cant calculate result on my own.

Source data is

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 exe   velocity  days sequence term  amt
    1              1   1.666667   10         9  20   507.44 
", header=TRUE)
```

Model looks like this:

```
model <- glm(
    formula =
      exe ~
      velocity +
      days +
      sequence +
      term +
      amt
    data = df,
    family = binomial
  )
```

Coeficients of this model are

```
(Intercept)                 velocity                     days                sequence                    term                     amt 
-0.8519663862            0.4389537214           -0.0011613631           -0.0433850503           -0.0050228834            0.0005687273
```

If I undrestood correctly, I should by able to replicate this model by this

```
((-0.8519663862)+(0.4389537214*1.666667)+(-0.0011613631*10)+(-0.0433850503*9)+(-0.0050228834*20)+(0.0005687273*507.44))
```

But result of my calculation is -0.3343185, but proper score calculated by model is 0.4171902. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: the first is on the log-odds scale, the second on the probability scale. Try `1 / (1 + exp(0.3343185))` (or using the inbuilt function `plogis(-0.3343185)`)

Comment: see [here](https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/glm.html) for an overview over the default link functions used by glm for different distribution families